# Vim Command Mode

Tags: vim, editor, command

I'm using gVIM which defaults to insert mode. When I press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) to enter command mode, nothing happens. I've searched for an alternative route to enter command mode. Does anyone know what the problem may be or another way to enter command mode?

Note: I'm running Windows 7 64-bit and gVim Easy 7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gVim-easy doesn't have modes. If you want modes you must use gVim.

Comment: Thanks, this is my second time diving into Vim (via gVim-Easy) and I'm almost certain that I've used modes prior to experiencing this problem. And when I access Vim as my editor through GitBash, it defaults to command mode. But I'll download gVim and try it.

Comment: I've searched my system for Vim, which I have. Seems more difficult to understand and open files. But <ESC> does result in command mode. Thanks

Comment: It is my understanding that gVim-easy is distributed WITH gVim. Am I wrong? Anyway, any so-called easy version of gVim will only give you bad habits and false expectations. Go with straight gVim (or better in a console) and start with vimtutor.

Comment: Point taken. I appreciate the help.

Comment: The key point @romainl is making is that you should really run `vimtutor`.  It's a quick way to get into Vim, the right way.

Comment: -1: If I am not mistaking what you are referring to, `egvim` (that is `gvim -y` or `gvim --cmd 'source $VIMRUNTIME/evim.vim'`) *does* have modes. Read `:h 'insertmode'`, it states explicitely how normal mode can be accessed.

Comment: @ZyX, I've never used it and I haven't Vim installed on my aunt's PC so I can't tell for sure. All I know about Vim's easy mode is what I've read on some web pages ([here](http://goo.gl/DjjTy) and [here](http://goo.gl/229E1) and [there on the doc itself](http://goo.gl/f3WOQ) + [there](http://goo.gl/pxNVL)). I'll be glad if I (and those pages' authors) am proven wrong.

Comment: @romainl I haven't used it too, but I used to set `'insertmode'` option in order to get vim start with insert mode to quickly write something there (and found it *very* inconvenient that I can't switch to normal mode). In any case 1. you can't call something vim if it does not have modes, 2. before writing these you should have thought how much work have to be done in order to purge them (easy vim comes with standart distribution, so there should not be any other editor) and 3. what is 'easy vim' is clearly stated in documentation. `$VIMRUNTIME/evim.vim` script is not hard to read.

Comment: @ZyX I'm not sure if you agree with me or not. Anyway, my answer is definetely "black & white" but I wanted it that way. I felt that the asker was taking a wrong path (evim instead of vim) and I wanted to help him take a "better" path. sehe's answer is probably the right one.

Comment: @romainl I agree about using normal vim, but I argue about the 'gvim-easy does not have modes' statement that is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If you MUST use gVim Easy *and* command mode:

<kbd>C-o</kbd>`:echo "Woot!"`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

will do what you expect; Also,

1. to enter command line history edit window:

   <kbd>C-o</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>  <sub>(leave history window with <kbd>C-c</kbd>)</sub>
2. to enter multiple command mode commands in sequence:

   <kbd>C-o</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> <sub>(leave Ex mode with `vi`<kbd>Enter</kbd>)</sub>

I sometimes use tricks like this to manipulate undo information or to record mini macros on the fly (<sub><kbd>C-o</kbd><kbd>qq</kbd></sub> e.g.)